# Stop users inserting duplicate rows into table

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

So I have a database that inserts data fine. But I need it so 3 of the columns will never be the same as another 3.

E.g Period 3 on 04/28/2014 room 027.

I dont think making the fields UNIQUE will help so is the best thing I can do is do an SQL check to see if those 3 already exist and `if ($row == 1)` then echo "cannot enter duplicate

```
 else {   $sql= "INSERT INTO Booking (Date, Period, Type, RoomID, Username) VALUES ('$bookdate','$bookperiod','$booktype','$bookroom','$username')";   
    $insert = sqlite_exec($con,$sql) }
```

Or is there a better way around this?

Comment: Adding a `UNIQUE` index on the columns or a combination of columns seems like the perfect solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a composite unique index.  A "composite" index has multiple columns.  You create it using:

```
create unique index booking_date_period_roomid on booking(Date, Period, RoomId)
```

You can also put this in the `create table` statement using the `unique` keyword.